# Not all folders returned by boto3 Bucket.objects.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

My S3 bucket contains a bunch of files in a multilevel folder structure. I'm trying to identify the top level folders in the hierarchy, but `objects.all()` returns some but not all folders as distinct `ObjectSummary` objects. Why?

Sample file structure:

```
file1.txt
a/file2.txt
a/a1/file3.txt
b/b1/file4.txt
```

Desired output: `[a,b]`

What I'm doing:

```
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('mybucket').objects.all()
```

This returns the following `ObjectSummary` objects:

```
file1.txt
a/
a/file2.txt
a/a1/file3.txt
b/b1/file4.txt
```

Notice that `a/` is listed as a separate entry, *but `b/` is not*, while the files in `b/` are.

I could understand it returning neither, as folders are technically not distinct entities, or both, but why are some folders returned and others not?

I also understand there could be other ways to achieve my objective, but I want to understand why boto3 is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 does have the concept of creating a folder, through a [Create Folder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html#create-folder) button, which creates a dedicated object with just the folder name, separate from the files that have this as a prefix.

`a/` in the example above was a folder I created manually, but I hadn't done this for `b/`.

Comment: `a/` is not a folder. This is only AWS console concept, and you just coppied basically my answer when you write "which creates a dedicated object with just the folder name".

Comment: Having the ability to create one manually through a  "Create Folder" button is a key insight that distinguishes our answers, so no sorry, my answer is not a copy. I get that it's not a folder in the traditional, disk-based allocation table OS, but the S3 console's language of "creating a folder" gives this S3 Object sufficient meaning to be referred to as one for the purpose of file organization as well as the context of this question.

Comment: The folder is only AWS console concept. Folders don't exist in S3 as stated in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html): "Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system.". S3 is flat, there are not folders nor subfolders. Its only confusing construct of AWS console which leads to your question.

Comment: To some extent, disk-based OS folders are also just a concept. [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html#public-folders) also states that "When you make a folder public, anyone on the internet can view all the objects that are grouped in that folder." We can quibble about calling it a folder, but in some ways it behaves like one, and distinctly from "file" objects.

Comment: So how come only after I wrote "You don't have /b "folder", because there is no object called precisely /b", you made your answer with " dedicated object with just the folder name" if you already understand how S3 works?

Comment: I was independently scanning the AWS console for clues at that time, saw the "Create Folder" button and remembered that I had clicked it for some folders and not for others. I realized that there is a distinction between folders that are explicitly created in the console vs. those implicitly existing as file prefixes. Your answer made more sense after I had this realization, but it was my own insight that led to my answer, and as I said, it's the fact that you have the option to "Create a Folder" that led me into and out of this problem. Thank you for your answer though. It isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I could understand it returning neither, as folders are technically not distinct entities, or both, but why are some folders returned and others not?

There are **no folders** in S3. A concept of a folder does not exist in object storage which is S3. What you call a "folder" is just a visual representation of an object with the key `a/` or `b/`. Basically AWS console artificially calls everything with `/` a folder leading to all this confusion.

So `a/` is just an object (not folder) called `a/`. You don't have `/b` "folder", because there is no object called precisely `/b`. Instead you have an object which is called `b/b1/file4.txt` (not `b/`).

Comment: I understand that. My question is why do I get `a/` but not `b/` in the list?

Comment: @Steven I already wrote: So a/ is just an object (not folder) called a/. You don't have /b "folder", because there is no object called precisely /b

Answer (score 0):

To identify "top-level folders", you can use:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='BUCKET-NAME',Delimiter='/')
prefix_list = [dict['Prefix'] for dict in response['CommonPrefixes']]
print(prefix_list)
```

By specifying `Delimiter='/'` it returns a list of `CommonPrefixes` that are effectively the folder names.